# Exploring the [explorer] tags

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

Doing some review tasks, I came across the [explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/explorer) and the [windows-explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-explorer) tags. I think that *the first should* (quite obviously) *be a synonym for the later* but as I do not have the necessary reputation to file a request, I would like to try and persuade some more privileged user to do it.

---

[explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/explorer) Tag wiki:

> Windows Explorer is the file manager and navigation tool that exists in Microsoft Windows operating systems

---

[windows-explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-explorer) Tag wiki:

> Windows Explorer is a file manager application that is included with releases of the Microsoft Windows operating system from Windows 95 onwards.

---

In my humble opinion, I think that *[windows-explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-explorer) should be the master*, despite having less tagged questions (393 as opposed to 744), but the *windows-* prefix offers distinction to tags like [package-explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/package-explorer), [team-explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/team-explorer) and even more.

Comment: And maybe, we could add to the tag wiki that most questions probably belong on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: @ClausJørgensen Don't a lot of the questions deal with programmatically manipulating Windows Explorer, which is on topic for SO?

Comment: @ZevSpitz I took a quick glance at the questions, and it's a minority that's on topic for SO.